# Can we use react.js in Webview from the source directory in react naitve?

Tags: react-native

I built WebView to access an HTML.
in the HTML file I work with React.JS .
Now I draw  Babel and React.JS libraries from the Internet in html script.
I want to import from my existing library at React-native directly.

i try this in the HTML(and it's not working):

```
<script type="text/babel">
 "use strict";
 import React from 'react';
... </script>
```